# Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky MAC

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I am getting, `"Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky"`
in macOS mojave while installing postgres using brew. (`brew install postgresql`)

Unfortunately the answers found for this question in SO for Linux distribution, not for macOS users.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did

```
sudo chmod +t /private/tmp
```

It worked.